# multiply columns/rows in one R dataset with values from another

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the two following datasets:

```
Dataset1                                 Dataset2

Kingdom  P1  P2  P5  P6  P7  T4  T6      P1  P2  P5  P6  P7  T4  T6
Virus    5   4   4   5   5   3   3       3   4   4   2   1   1   6
Bacteria 3   3   4   6   1   2   1       
Animal   1   2   3   4   4   1   5     
etc.
```

I need to multiply every column of dataset1 by the corresponding values in dataset2. For example the value for P1 in dataset2 needs to multiply every row of the P1 column in dataset1 by 3.
What I am showing here it's just an excerpt of my data. Dataset1 has thousands of inputs.

If those two datasets get multiplied, the output would look something like this:

```
Kingdom  P1  P2  P5  P6  P7  T4  T6                    
Virus    15  16  16  10   5   3  18                      
Bacteria 9   12  16  12   1   2   6       
Animal   3   8   12   8   4   1  30     
etc.
```

Any ideas on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `mapply` to multiply each column from `Dataset1` and `Dataset2`. `Dataset2` is the final output.

```
Dataset3 <- Dataset1
Dataset3[, -1]<- mapply(`*`, Dataset1[, -1], Dataset2)
Dataset3
#    Kingdom P1 P2 P5 P6 P7 T4 T6
# 1    Virus 15 16 16 10  5  3 18
# 2 Bacteria  9 12 16 12  1  2  6
# 3   Animal  3  8 12  8  4  1 30
```

**DATA**

```
Dataset1 <- read.table(text = "Kingdom  P1  P2  P5  P6  P7  T4  T6
Virus    5   4   4   5   5   3   3       
Bacteria 3   3   4   6   1   2   1       
Animal   1   2   3   4   4   1   5",
                       header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Dataset2 <- read.table(text = "P1  P2  P5  P6  P7  T4  T6
                       3   4   4   2   1   1   6",
                       header = TRUE)
```

Comment: You could also use `Map` to avoid `mapply`'s `simplify2array` that isn't necessary in this case. Might speed things up ever so slightly in the case of big data.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `apply`

```
> do.call(rbind, apply(Dataset1[,-1], 1, "*", Dataset2))
  P1 P2 P5 P6 P7 T4 T6
1 15 16 16 10  5  3 18
2  9 12 16 12  1  2  6
3  3  8 12  8  4  1 30
```

`Dataset1` and `Dataset2` are defined as in @www's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just do a direct multiplication. This will probably be the fastest solution:

```
cbind(Dataset1[1],t(t(Dataset1[-1])*unlist(Dataset2)))
   Kingdom P1 P2 P5 P6 P7 T4 T6
1    Virus 15 16 16 10  5  3 18
2 Bacteria  9 12 16 12  1  2  6
3   Animal  3  8 12  8  4  1 30
```

You can also do `cbind(Dataset1[1],t(t(Dataset1[-1])*c(t(Dataset2))))`

You can also use `sweep`

```
cbind(Dataset1[1],sweep(Dataset1[-1],2,unlist(Dataset2),"*"))

   Kingdom P1 P2 P5 P6 P7 T4 T6
1    Virus 15 16 16 10  5  3 18
2 Bacteria  9 12 16 12  1  2  6
3   Animal  3  8 12  8  4  1 30
```

Comment: Also `Dataset1[-1] * Dataset2[rep(1,nrow(Dataset1)),]` to do a direct multiplication without `t`ransposing.

Comment: Yeah.. Although did not want to repeat. Thought it wont be faster

Comment: And you'd be correct. Just did a quick check and doing the double transpose is actually much quicker. I really didn't think it would be, but there you go :-)

Comment: Maybe `Dataset1[-1] * rep(unlist(Dataset2), each=nrow(Dataset1))`. Then you avoid the data.frame copies.

Comment: @lmo - definitely quicker than my suggestion, but still much slower than the double `t()`

Comment: @thelatemail That is surprising. Maybe matrices are that much faster for these operations.

Comment: oh matrices are vectorized. It works on the whole matrix.. No repetition nothing... That's why they are faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using dplyr and tidyr packages.

Let's assume this is your dataset:

```
ds_1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Kingdom  P1  P2  P5  P6  P7  T4  T6
Virus    5   4   4   5   5   3   3 
Bacteria 3   3   4   6   1   2   1       
Animal   1   2   3   4   4   1   5")

   Kingdom P1 P2 P5 P6 P7 T4 T6
1    Virus  5  4  4  5  5  3  3
2 Bacteria  3  3  4  6  1  2  1
3   Animal  1  2  3  4  4  1  5

ds_2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "P1  P2  P5  P6  P7  T4  T6
3   4   4   2   1   1   6")

  P1 P2 P5 P6 P7 T4 T6
1  3  4  4  2  1  1  6
```

1. Switch from wide to long, using tidyr's `gather()`:

   ```
   ds_1 <- ds_1 %>% gather(Key, Value, -Kingdom)

       Kingdom Key Value
   1     Virus  P1     5
   2  Bacteria  P1     3
   3    Animal  P1     1
   4     Virus  P2     4
   5  Bacteria  P2     3
   6    Animal  P2     2
   ...

   ds_2 <- ds_2 %>% gather(Key, Multiplier)

       Key Multiplier
    1  P1          3
    2  P2          4
    3  P5          4
    4  P6          2
    ...
   ```
2. Now, you can just merge to two dataframes using dplyr's `left_join()` and multiply using `mutate()`:

   ```
   ds_1 %>% left_join(ds_2, by = "Key") %>%
       mutate(Value = Value * Multiplier) %>%
       select(-Multiplier)

        Kingdom Key Value
    1     Virus  P1    15
    2  Bacteria  P1     9
    3    Animal  P1     3
    4     Virus  P2    16
    5  Bacteria  P2    12
    6    Animal  P2     8
    7     Virus  P5    16
    8  Bacteria  P5    16
    ...
   ```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `apply` and array multiplication.

```
cbind(Dataset1[1], do.call(rbind, apply(Dataset1[-1], 1, function(x)(x*Dataset2[1,]))))

#    Kingdom P1 P2 P5 P6 P7 T4 T6
# 1    Virus 15 16 16 10  5  3 18
# 2 Bacteria  9 12 16 12  1  2  6
# 3   Animal  3  8 12  8  4  1 30
```

**Note:** The above answer is quite similar to the one by @JilberUrbina.

**Data:**

```
Dataset1 <- read.table(text =                                 
"Kingdom  P1  P2  P5  P6  P7  T4  T6      
Virus    5   4   4   5   5   3   3       
Bacteria 3   3   4   6   1   2   1       
Animal   1   2   3   4   4   1   5",
header = TRUE)


Dataset2 <- read.table(text =
"P1  P2  P5  P6  P7  T4  T6
3   4   4   2   1   1   6",
header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a for loop, if data1 is your first dataset and data2 is the second dataset, then:

```
for(i in 1:dim(data2)[2]){
      data1[,i] <- data1[,i]*data2
}
```